# Need to convert Checkbox to look like radion button using css Apprearace property

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

It seems like appearance property is being updated in css3.I used to work with below code 1 month ago and it was working fine. But now appearance property is not converting checkbox to radio button. I have tried it on several browsers but no luck.

Can anyone please let me know why it is not working now? and provide me the better solution. SO my checkbox just look like radio button.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: radio; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-appearance: radio;    /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: radio;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> Radio button 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> Radio button 2</label>
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
```

Comment: In the 1st code-snippet you are rendering checkbox and making it appear like radio.  Whereas in the 2nd code-snippet you're rendering radio and making it appear like checkbox.  Seems to work fine.

Comment: When I am running it,  it is not converting in both the case on my system(Browser used Firefox 80.0 (32-bit)) .Have you tried to run it?If it is working for you which browser you are using for it?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox version 79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the CSS appearance property other than `none` and `auto` will not be supported in all the newer versions of major browsers. This is to preserve the original semantics of the widgets across browsers.

[W3 Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-4/#appearance-switching)

The only way to convert your checkboxes into "radio buttons" now is to manually override the default css styling of the element with your custom css.

Something like this:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border:1px solid #777;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
  background-color: black;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="01"><label for="01">Radio button 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="02"><label for="02">Radio button 2</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it worked before, it's probably a change in your version of FireFox 80.0 (**32bit**) or you used a 64bit version. I tested on FireFox 79.0 (**64bit**) and your css worked fine.

**Mozilla.org says appearance (-moz-appearance, -webkit-appearance) is an experimental techonlogy.** So use it with caution.

They mention:
*From version 62: this feature is behind the layout.css.webkit-appearance.enabled preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config.*

Check to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that is correct It is working fine on Firefox 79.0(64 bit). I have tries to add the "layout.css.webkit-appearance.enabled" in about:config in Firefox 80.0. But it is not working. Is there any way i can make it work for every browser?

Comment: Unfortunately, not every browser support it according to the Mozilla compatibility table listed on their site.